# Why can't I use the 'size' command in FTP?

Tags: windows, ftp

I made a screenshot of my operation as below on [Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP). As the remotehelp says, the `size` command should be implemented. But I got a `invalid command`. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Invalid command" means that the client doesn't support it. Since the server does, though, you should be able to do something like this:

```
quote size tags
```

And if all is well, you'll get a numeric code for the response (should be 213) followed by the file size.

Answer (score 3):

If `SIZE` doesn't work there is nothing you can do locally. It's a problem with the FTP server.

However, 
`tags` is usually the name of a directory<sup>**(*)**</sup> and `SIZE` usually only works on files. So perhaps that's your problem.

**(*)** In [Subversion](http://www.germane-software.com/~ser/R_n_R/subversion.html) it is customary to organize your project in three top directories called *branches*, *tags* and *trunk*

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.I'm quite sure `tags` is file since I work on the linux machine of the FTP server.And just now  I did this on linux,the message is `550 SIZE not allowed in ASCII mode`..

Comment: @SpawnST - Have you tried switching to binary mode?

Comment: the switching fix problem on Linux,but on Windows the error still be there.